# High memory consumption on Gremlin query (using Neptune)

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlin-server

I running out of "freeable memory" on my Neptune cluster when running this query multiple times:

```
g.V().
  has('User', 'uuid', 'c4746c15-4f8e-42a4-97d3-8e2d25de2dc0').
  repeat(__.both('belongsTo').hasLabel('Group')).
    until(__.has('Group', 'kind', 'site').or().loops().is((int) 2)).
  filter(
    __.out('belongsTo').
    has('Group', 'uuid', '2da18428-538b-4b6a-b908-9f0edf7af422')).
  in('belongsTo').
  hasLabel('Person').
  dedup().
  project('person', 'siteName', 'siteId', 'encounters').
    by(__.valueMap()).
    by(__.out('belongsTo').values('tag')).
    by(__.out('belongsTo').values('uuid')).
    by(__.in('belongsTo').hasLabel('Encounter').valueMap().fold())
```

I would assume that the `repeat` part could trigger a memory issue so I put a limit over there, but that doesn't seem to prevent the memory issue from happening.

Any ideas?

UPDATED the Neptune profile information from the request:

```
*******************************************************
                Neptune Gremlin Profile
*******************************************************

Query String
==================
g.V().has('User','uuid','c4746c15-4f8e-42a4-97d3-8e2d25de2dc0').repeat(__.both('belongsTo').hasLabel('Group')).until(__.has('Group','kind','site').or().loops().is(2)).filter(__.out('belongsTo').has('Group','uuid','2da18428-538b-4b6a-b908-9f0edf7af422')).in('belongsTo').hasLabel('Person').dedup().project('person','siteName','siteId','encounters').by(__.valueMap()).by(__.out('belongsTo').values('tag')).by(__.out('belongsTo').values('uuid')).by(__.in('belongsTo').hasLabel('Encounter').valueMap().fold())

Original Traversal
==================
[GraphStep(vertex,
    []), HasStep([~label.eq(User), uuid.eq(c4746c15-4f8e-42a4-97d3-8e2d25de2dc0)
    ]), RepeatStep([VertexStep(BOTH,
        [belongsTo
        ],vertex), HasStep([~label.eq(Group)
        ]), RepeatEndStep
    ],until([HasStep([~label.eq(Group), kind.eq(site)
        ]), OrStep, LoopsStep, IsStep(eq(2))
    ]),emit(false)), TraversalFilterStep([VertexStep(OUT,
        [belongsTo
        ],vertex), HasStep([~label.eq(Group), uuid.eq(2da18428-538b-4b6a-b908-9f0edf7af422)
        ])
    ]), VertexStep(IN,
    [belongsTo
    ],vertex), HasStep([~label.eq(Person)
    ]), DedupGlobalStep(null,null), ProjectStep([person, siteName, siteId, encounters
    ],
    [
        [PropertyMapStep(value)
        ],
        [VertexStep(OUT,
            [belongsTo
            ],vertex), PropertiesStep([tag
            ],value)
        ],
        [VertexStep(OUT,
            [belongsTo
            ],vertex), PropertiesStep([uuid
            ],value)
        ],
        [VertexStep(IN,
            [belongsTo
            ],vertex), HasStep([~label.eq(Encounter)
            ]), PropertyMapStep(value), FoldStep
        ]
    ])
]

Optimized Traversal
===================
Neptune steps: [
    NeptuneGraphQueryStep(Vertex) {
        JoinGroupNode {
            PatternNode[(?1, <uuid>,
                "c4746c15-4f8e-42a4-97d3-8e2d25de2dc0", <~>) . project ?1 .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=1, expectedTotalOutput=1, indexTime=0, joinTime=0, numSearches=1, actualTotalOutput=1
            }
            PatternNode[(?1, <~label>, ?2=<User>, <~>) . project ask .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=382, expectedTotalInput=1, expectedTotalOutput=1, indexTime=0, joinTime=0, numSearches=1, actualTotalOutput=1
            }
            RepeatNode {
                Repeat {
                    JoinGroupNode {
                        UnionNode {
                            PatternNode[(?3, ?6=<belongsTo>, ?4, ?7) . project ?3,?4 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?7) .
                            ],
                            {cacheJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=37640, indexTime=0, joinTime=3, numSearches=2
                            }
                            PatternNode[(?4, ?6=<belongsTo>, ?3, ?7) . project ?3,?4 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?7) .
                            ],
                            {cacheJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=37640, indexTime=0, joinTime=1, numSearches=2
                            }
                        },
                        {estimatedCardinality=75280
                        }
                        PatternNode[(?4, <~label>, ?5=<Group>, <~>) . project ask .
                        ],
                        {hashJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=100, indexTime=0, joinTime=0
                        }
                    }
                }
                Until {
                    JoinGroupNode[project ask
                    ] {
                        PatternNode[(?4, <~label>, ?8=<Group>, <~>) .
                        ],
                        {hashJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=100, indexTime=1, joinTime=0
                        }
                        PatternNode[(?4, <kind>,
                            "site", <~>) . project ask .
                        ],
                        {hashJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=87, indexTime=0, joinTime=0
                        }
                    }
                }
                LoopsCondition {
                    UnionNode[project ask
                    ] {
                        LoopsFilter(?3,eq(2))
                    }
                }
            }, inputVar=?1, outputVar=?9, leftVar=?3, rightVar=?4, annotations={emitFirst=false, untilFirst=false, repeatMode=BFS, expectedTotalOutput=84, actualTotalOutput=84
            }
            JoinGroupNode[project ask
            ] {
                PatternNode[(?9, ?12=<belongsTo>, ?10, ?13) . project ?9,?10 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?13) .
                ],
                {estimatedCardinality=37640, expectedTotalInput=84, joinRatio=0.5, expectedTotalOutput=42, indexTime=18, joinTime=5, numSearches=84, actualTotalOutput=84
                }
                PatternNode[(?10, <~label>, ?11=<Group>, <~>) . project ask .
                ],
                {estimatedCardinality=100, expectedTotalInput=42, indexTime=0, hashJoin=true, joinRatio=1.0, expectedTotalOutput=42, joinTime=1, actualTotalOutput=84
                }
                PatternNode[(?10, <uuid>,
                    "2da18428-538b-4b6a-b908-9f0edf7af422", <~>) . project ask .
                ],
                {estimatedCardinality=1, expectedTotalInput=42, indexTime=0, hashJoin=true, joinTime=0
                }
            },
            {expectedTotalOutput=82, actualTotalOutput=82
            }
            PatternNode[(?14, ?16=<belongsTo>, ?9, ?17) . project ?9,?14 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?17) .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=37640, expectedTotalInput=82, expectedTotalOutput=974, indexTime=0, joinTime=3, numSearches=41, actualTotalOutput=974
            }
            PatternNode[(?14, <~label>, ?15=<Person>, <~>) . project ask .
            ],
            {estimatedCardinality=399, expectedTotalInput=974, indexTime=0, hashJoin=true, joinTime=2
            }
        }, finishers=[dedup(?14)
        ],
        {path=[Vertex(?1):GraphStep, Repeat[̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶(̶?̶3̶)̶:̶G̶r̶a̶p̶h̶S̶t̶e̶p̶, Vertex(?4):VertexStep, ̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶(̶?̶9̶)̶:̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶S̶t̶e̶p̶
                ], Vertex(?14):VertexStep
            ], joinStats=true, optimizationTime=7, maxVarId=38, executionTime=305
        }
    },
    NeptuneProjectStep {
        NeptunePropertyMapStep {
            JoinGroupNode {
                PatternNode[(?14, ?18, ?19, <~>) . CompareFilter(?18 != <~label>) .
                ]
            },
            {initialValues={?1=null, ?3=null, ?4=null, ?9=null, ?14=null
                }
            }
        },
        NeptuneGraphQueryStep(PropertyValue) {
            JoinGroupNode {
                PatternNode[(?14, ?22=<belongsTo>, ?20, ?23) . project ?14,?20 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?23) .
                ],
                {estimatedCardinality=37640, expectedTotalOutput=37640, indexTime=2, joinTime=39, numSearches=225, actualTotalOutput=225
                }
                PatternNode[(?20, ?24=<tag>, ?25, <~>) . project ?20,?25 .
                ],
                {estimatedCardinality=100, expectedTotalInput=37640, indexTime=0, hashJoin=true, joinRatio=1.0, expectedTotalOutput=37640, joinTime=3, actualTotalOutput=225
                }
            },
            {executionTime=93378, initialValues={?1=null, ?9=null, ?3=null, ?4=null, ?14=null
                }, path=[Vertex(?1):GraphStep, Repeat[̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶(̶?̶3̶)̶:̶G̶r̶a̶p̶h̶S̶t̶e̶p̶, Vertex(?4):VertexStep, ̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶(̶?̶9̶)̶:̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶S̶t̶e̶p̶
                    ], Vertex(?14):VertexStep, Vertex(?20):VertexStep, PropertyValue(?25):PropertiesStep
                ], actualTotalOutput=225, optimizationTime=7, maxVarId=38, joinStats=true, expectedTotalOutput=37640, joinRatio=1.0
            }
        },
        NeptuneGraphQueryStep(PropertyValue) {
            JoinGroupNode {
                PatternNode[(?14, ?28=<belongsTo>, ?26, ?29) . project ?14,?26 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?29) .
                ],
                {estimatedCardinality=37640, expectedTotalOutput=37640, indexTime=0, joinTime=9, numSearches=225, actualTotalOutput=225
                }
                PatternNode[(?26, ?30=<uuid>, ?31, <~>) . project ?26,?31 .
                ],
                {estimatedCardinality=59952, expectedTotalInput=37640, joinRatio=0.5, expectedTotalOutput=18820, indexTime=1, joinTime=33, numSearches=225, actualTotalOutput=225
                }
            },
            {executionTime=92852, initialValues={?1=null, ?9=null, ?3=null, ?4=null, ?14=null
                }, path=[Vertex(?1):GraphStep, Repeat[̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶(̶?̶3̶)̶:̶G̶r̶a̶p̶h̶S̶t̶e̶p̶, Vertex(?4):VertexStep, ̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶(̶?̶9̶)̶:̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶S̶t̶e̶p̶
                    ], Vertex(?14):VertexStep, Vertex(?26):VertexStep, PropertyValue(?31):PropertiesStep
                ], actualTotalOutput=225, optimizationTime=7, maxVarId=38, joinStats=true, expectedTotalOutput=18820, joinRatio=1.0
            }
        },
        NeptuneGraphQueryStep(Vertex) {
            JoinGroupNode {
                PatternNode[(?32, ?34=<belongsTo>, ?14, ?35) . project ?14,?32 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?35) .
                ],
                {estimatedCardinality=37640, expectedTotalOutput=37640, indexTime=0, joinTime=8, numSearches=225, actualTotalOutput=675
                }
                PatternNode[(?32, <~label>, ?33=<Encounter>, <~>) . project ask .
                ],
                {estimatedCardinality=1184, expectedTotalInput=37640, indexTime=1, hashJoin=true, joinRatio=1.0, expectedTotalOutput=37640, joinTime=1, actualTotalOutput=675
                }
            },
            {executionTime=62115, initialValues={?1=null, ?9=null, ?3=null, ?4=null, ?14=null
                }, path=[Vertex(?1):GraphStep, Repeat[̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶(̶?̶3̶)̶:̶G̶r̶a̶p̶h̶S̶t̶e̶p̶, Vertex(?4):VertexStep, ̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶(̶?̶9̶)̶:̶V̶e̶r̶t̶e̶x̶S̶t̶e̶p̶
                    ], Vertex(?14):VertexStep, Vertex(?32):VertexStep
                ], actualTotalOutput=675, optimizationTime=7, maxVarId=38, joinStats=true, expectedTotalOutput=37640, joinRatio=1.0
            }
        },
        NeptunePropertyMapStep {
            JoinGroupNode {
                PatternNode[(?32, ?36, ?37, <~>) . CompareFilter(?36 != <~label>) .
                ]
            },
            {initialValues={?32=null, ?1=null, ?3=null, ?4=null, ?9=null, ?14=null
                }
            }
        }
    },
    NeptuneTraverserConverterStep
]


Physical Pipeline
=================
NeptuneGraphQueryStep
    |-- StartOp
    |-- JoinGroupOp@1c433fca
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@4cd84dd5(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?1, <uuid>,
    "c4746c15-4f8e-42a4-97d3-8e2d25de2dc0", <~>) . project ?1 .
],
{estimatedCardinality=1, expectedTotalOutput=1
}))
        |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @4cd84dd5, null)
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@6a2d91c0(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?1, <~label>, ?2=<User>, <~>) . project ask .
],
{estimatedCardinality=382, expectedTotalInput=1, expectedTotalOutput=1
}))
        |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @6a2d91c0, @4cd84dd5)
        |-- RepeatOp
            |-- <upstream input> (Iteration 0) [visited=1, output=0 (until=0, emit=0), next=1
]
            |-- BindingSetQueue (Iteration 1) [visited=2, output=0 (until=0, emit=0), next=2
]
                |-- JoinGroupOp@469e9999
                    |-- UnionOp@432653ef
                        |-- MultiplexerOp
                            |-- BindingSetQueue
                            |-- DynamicJoinOp@4d1e18bb(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?4, ?6=<belongsTo>, ?3, ?7) . project ?3,?4 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?7) .
],
{cacheJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=37640
}))
                            |-- BindingSetQueue
                            |-- DynamicJoinOp@4bbb2349(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?3, ?6=<belongsTo>, ?4, ?7) . project ?3,?4 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?7) .
],
{cacheJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=37640
}))
                    |-- DynamicJoinOp@79db29f6(HashJoinOp(PatternNode[(?4, <~label>, ?5=<Group>, <~>) . project ask .
],
{hashJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=100, indexTime=0
}))
            |-- BindingSetQueue (Iteration 2) [visited=84, output=84 (until=84, emit=0), next=0
]
                |-- JoinGroupOp@469e9999
                    |-- UnionOp@432653ef
                        |-- MultiplexerOp
                            |-- BindingSetQueue
                            |-- DynamicJoinOp@4d1e18bb(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?4, ?6=<belongsTo>, ?3, ?7) . project ?3,?4 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?7) .
],
{cacheJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=37640
}))
                            |-- BindingSetQueue
                            |-- DynamicJoinOp@4bbb2349(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?3, ?6=<belongsTo>, ?4, ?7) . project ?3,?4 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?7) .
],
{cacheJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=37640
}))
                    |-- DynamicJoinOp@79db29f6(HashJoinOp(PatternNode[(?4, <~label>, ?5=<Group>, <~>) . project ask .
],
{hashJoin=true, estimatedCardinality=100, indexTime=0
}))
        |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @893b409, @6a2d91c0)
        |-- JoinGroupOp@35f5be60
            |-- AskOp
                |-- BindingSetQueue
                |-- DynamicJoinOp@27c672fc(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?9, ?12=<belongsTo>, ?10, ?13) . project ?9,?10 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?13) .
],
{estimatedCardinality=37640, expectedTotalInput=84, joinRatio=0.5, expectedTotalOutput=42
}))
                |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @27c672fc, @893b409)
                |-- DynamicJoinOp@7f26b6b(HashJoinOp(PatternNode[(?10, <~label>, ?11=<Group>, <~>) . project ask .
],
{estimatedCardinality=100, expectedTotalInput=42, indexTime=0, hashJoin=true, joinRatio=1.0, expectedTotalOutput=42
}))
                |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @7f26b6b, @27c672fc)
                |-- DynamicJoinOp@12d4a460(HashJoinOp(PatternNode[(?10, <uuid>,
    "2da18428-538b-4b6a-b908-9f0edf7af422", <~>) . project ask .
],
{estimatedCardinality=1, expectedTotalInput=42, indexTime=0, hashJoin=true
}))
        |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @35f5be60, isJoinRatioOp=true)
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@a4a1ee4(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?14, ?16=<belongsTo>, ?9, ?17) . project ?9,?14 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?17) .
],
{estimatedCardinality=37640, expectedTotalInput=82, expectedTotalOutput=974
}))
        |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @a4a1ee4, @35f5be60)
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@1e8fccc3(HashJoinOp(PatternNode[(?14, <~label>, ?15=<Person>, <~>) . project ask .
],
{estimatedCardinality=399, expectedTotalInput=974, indexTime=0, hashJoin=true
}))
        |-- FilterOp

NeptuneProjectStep
    |-- BindingSetQueue
    |-- JoinGroupOp@3a55f0ca
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@31340f0b(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?14, ?18, ?19, <~>) . CompareFilter(?18 != <~label>) .
]))
    
    |-- BindingSetQueue
    |-- JoinGroupOp@ab2554a
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@3df217d8(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?14, ?22=<belongsTo>, ?20, ?23) . project ?14,?20 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?23) .
],
{estimatedCardinality=37640, expectedTotalOutput=37640
}))
        |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @3df217d8, null)
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@679593bc(HashJoinOp(PatternNode[(?20, ?24=<tag>, ?25, <~>) . project ?20,?25 .
],
{estimatedCardinality=100, expectedTotalInput=37640, indexTime=0, hashJoin=true, joinRatio=1.0, expectedTotalOutput=37640
}))
        |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @679593bc, @3df217d8)
    |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @ab2554a, @679593bc)
    
    |-- BindingSetQueue
    |-- JoinGroupOp@71cb259
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@1f1cbff5(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?14, ?28=<belongsTo>, ?26, ?29) . project ?14,?26 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?29) .
],
{estimatedCardinality=37640, expectedTotalOutput=37640
}))
        |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @1f1cbff5, null)
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@32fd3719(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?26, ?30=<uuid>, ?31, <~>) . project ?26,?31 .
],
{estimatedCardinality=59952, expectedTotalInput=37640, joinRatio=0.5, expectedTotalOutput=18820
}))
        |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @32fd3719, @1f1cbff5)
    |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @71cb259, @32fd3719)
    
    |-- BindingSetQueue
    |-- JoinGroupOp@79be4a89
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@1b52b19d(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?32, ?34=<belongsTo>, ?14, ?35) . project ?14,?32 . IsEdgeIdFilter(?35) .
],
{estimatedCardinality=37640, expectedTotalOutput=37640
}))
        |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @1b52b19d, null)
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@61cb4615(HashJoinOp(PatternNode[(?32, <~label>, ?33=<Encounter>, <~>) . project ask .
],
{estimatedCardinality=1184, expectedTotalInput=37640, indexTime=1, hashJoin=true, joinRatio=1.0, expectedTotalOutput=37640
}))
        |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @61cb4615, @1b52b19d)
    |-- SpoolerOp(1000, @79be4a89, @61cb4615)
    
    |-- BindingSetQueue
    |-- JoinGroupOp@3f648ee9
        |-- DynamicJoinOp@4a48cfe(PipelineJoinOp(PatternNode[(?32, ?36, ?37, <~>) . CompareFilter(?36 != <~label>) .
]))

Runtime (ms)
============
Query Execution: 306.521
Serialization: 28.401

Traversal Metrics
=================
Step                                                               Count  Traversers       Time (ms)    % Dur
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NeptuneGraphQueryStep(Vertex)                                        225         225          42.506    14.04
NeptuneProjectStep([
    [NeptunePropertyMapStep
    ],
    [...                   225         225         236.267    78.06
NeptuneTraverserConverterStep                                        225         225          23.888     7.89
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -         302.662        -

Repeat Metrics
==============
Iteration  Visited   Output    Until     Emit     Next
------------------------------------------------------
        0        1        0        0        0        1
        1        2        0        0        0        2
        2       84       84       84        0        0
------------------------------------------------------
                87       84       84        0        3

Predicates
==========
# of predicates: 265

Results
=======
Count: 225
Response serializer: application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json
Response size (bytes): 449308


Index Operations
================
Query execution:
    # of statement index ops: 1938
    # of unique statement index ops: 1710
    Duplication ratio: 1.13
    # of terms materialized: 0
Serialization:
    # of statement index ops: 1938
    # of unique statement index ops: 1710
    Duplication ratio: 1.13
    # of terms materialized: 0
```

Comment: There's a lot that could be going on here.  Are you able to provide a Neptune Gremlin Profile output? (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-profile-api.html). Also, what error message are you getting when running this query?  An Out of Memory Exception?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll update the answer with the profile. Yes, I realized the error because queries were starting to get a `MemoryLimitExceededException` error. The weird thing is that the query that exhausted the memory wasn't throwing an error itself, but all subsequent queries (really simple ones).

Comment: What size instance are you using?  If using a t4g.medium, I would not be surprised by this, as that is very memory constrained and really only meant for light experimentation.  We recommend any of the non t-class instances for production workloads or for load testing.  More details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/instance-types.html

Comment: Thanks @TaylorRiggan, I am using a serverless instance with a min: 2 max: 10 NCUs config